# Codeigniter - Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting a **Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string** error when I echo my **is_active** variable, I can work just fine with the username and is_logged_in variable, but not with the is_active variable, I'm wondering what I could be doing wrong here...

On my controller I did:

```
$username=$this->input->post("username");
            $activated_val=$this->membership_model->is_activated($username);

            $data = array(
                "username" => $this->input->post("username"),
                "is_logged_in" => true,
                "is_active" => $activated_val
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect("main");
```

My model function:

```
function is_activated($username){
        $query = "SELECT activated FROM members WHERE username=?";
        $result = $this->db->query($query, $username);

        return $result;
    }
```

And in my view:

```
$is_active= $this->session->userdata("is_active");
                echo $is_active;
```

Comment: What type is `$activated_val`? Normally storing objects in a session is not a good idea

Comment: In my table, the "activated" column is of the INT type.

Comment: And what type is `$activated_val` variable? `var_dump($activated_val);` Php says it's an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model change the `return` line from

```
return $result;
```

to

```
return $result->row()->activated;
```

The query returns a CodeIgniter object which is not even a result yet, after passing it to `row()` you get an object with your database column values as this object attributes, then you refer to the `activated` column value by getting(`->activated`) the corresponding attribute of this object.